# Eliminate some pattern from all columns in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, gsub

I want to eliminate from my dataset all the begining of the columns, precisely the part: "number:". I have tried the gsub function but in every column the pattern is different and there's 500 variables I don't know how to do it.
Maybe there's another way to read the data and directly eliminate this part.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: do you want the columns to only say "V"?

Comment: Pleaes read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note that it asks to NOT use images and instead show the output of dput(X) where X is your input object since no one can easily use it otherwise. Also please clarify what it is you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide reproducible data, but here is a possibility:

```
x <- c("1:484", "2:574", "9:567", "10:782", "15:892")
gsub(".*:", "", x)   # or gsub("[0-9]*:", "", x)
# [1] "484" "574" "567" "782" "892"
```